# How do you create a label field and display text in Troux?

Tags: xml

How do you display a text label in a portal in Troux?

I need to display information in a text field in Troux, but the only way I've discovered to do it is to create a name value pair with the information as the name field.  But, this will display a colon after the text. This doesn't seem like the right way to do it. Is there an easy way to display a text field with information or instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the "messageDiv" widget. Here's a real life example.

```
<group name="Workflow_AppReview-header">
 <group name="layoutConfig">
  <setting name="labelColumnWidth" value="0%"></setting>
  <list name="propertyBoxes">
   <group name="mainBox">
    <setting name="boxType" value="none"></setting>
    <list name="properties">
     <group name="message">
      <setting name="labelPosition" value="none"></setting>
      <setting name="widget" value="messageDiv"></setting>
      <group name="widgetConfig">
       <setting name="messageEL"><value>Please review the information below.</value>
       </setting>
       <setting name="styleWidth" value="100%"></setting>
      </group>
     </group>
    </list>
   </group>
  </list>
 </group>
</group>
```

Comment: I knew this had to be a built-into the product - Thank you